# Is there a way that I can return multiple columns from a subquery rather than repeating the subquery for each column? It works but takes too long

Tags: sql-server, subquery

> As you can see I'm trying to add 4 columns by repeating the subquery,
> this works but takes too long to be useful. I tried to put all the
> joins at the end but then I only get the records that have values in
> [dbo.permit_terms] whereas I want *all* the records from [dbo.prd]. I hope this makes
> sense and will be very grateful for an answer.

```
   SELECT WLC.name AS WELLCOMPL
    , WLC.id_subsidiary AS SUB
    , PD.Date
    , PD.days
    , PD.oil
    , PD.water
    , PD.gas
    , PD.interest
    , PD.operator
    , PD.comments
    , (
    SELECT PT.net_working_int_oil
        FROM dbo.prd AS P (NOLOCK)
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_compl AS W WITH (NOLOCK) ON (P.id_subsidiary = W.id_subsidiary) AND (P.id_wellborecompl = W.id) 
            left JOIN dbo.wellstring WITH (NOLOCK) ON W.id_wellstring = dbo.wellstring.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore wb WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.wellstring.id_wellbore = wb.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_permit WP WITH (NOLOCK) ON wb.id = WP.id_wellbore
            left JOIN dbo.permit  WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = WP.id_permit
            left JOIN dbo.permit_terms PT WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = PT.id_permit 
        where (p.[date] >= pt.start_date and p.[date] <=pt.end_date)
    --      AND W.[name] = WLC.[name] 
            AND p.id = pd.id
            AND pd.id_subsidiary = w.id_subsidiary
            AND P.deletedAt Is Null 
            AND W.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.wellstring.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.permit.deletedAt Is Null
            AND wb.deletedAt Is Null
            AND PT.deletedAt Is Null
    )
     as permit_interest 
    , (
    SELECT PT.operator
        FROM dbo.prd AS P (NOLOCK)
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_compl AS W WITH (NOLOCK) ON (P.id_subsidiary = W.id_subsidiary) AND (P.id_wellborecompl = W.id) 
            left JOIN dbo.wellstring WITH (NOLOCK) ON W.id_wellstring = dbo.wellstring.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore wb WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.wellstring.id_wellbore = wb.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_permit WP WITH (NOLOCK) ON wb.id = WP.id_wellbore
            left JOIN dbo.permit  WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = WP.id_permit
            left JOIN dbo.permit_terms PT WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = PT.id_permit 
        where (p.[date] >= pt.start_date and p.[date] <=pt.end_date)
    --      AND W.[name] = WLC.[name] 
            AND p.id = pd.id
            AND pd.id_subsidiary = w.id_subsidiary
            AND P.deletedAt Is Null 
            AND W.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.wellstring.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.permit.deletedAt Is Null
            AND wb.deletedAt Is Null
            AND PT.deletedAt Is Null
    )
     as permit_operator
    , (
    SELECT pd.oil*PT.net_working_int_oil/100
        FROM dbo.prd AS P (NOLOCK)
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_compl AS W WITH (NOLOCK) ON (P.id_subsidiary = W.id_subsidiary) AND (P.id_wellborecompl = W.id) 
            left JOIN dbo.wellstring WITH (NOLOCK) ON W.id_wellstring = dbo.wellstring.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore wb WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.wellstring.id_wellbore = wb.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_permit WP WITH (NOLOCK) ON wb.id = WP.id_wellbore
            left JOIN dbo.permit  WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = WP.id_permit
            left JOIN dbo.permit_terms PT WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = PT.id_permit 
        where (p.[date] >= pt.start_date and p.[date] <=pt.end_date)
    --      AND W.[name] = WLC.[name] 
            AND p.id = pd.id
            AND pd.id_subsidiary = w.id_subsidiary
            AND P.deletedAt Is Null 
            AND W.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.wellstring.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.permit.deletedAt Is Null
            AND wb.deletedAt Is Null
            AND PT.deletedAt Is Null
    )
     as Oil_net
    , (
    SELECT pd.gas*PT.net_working_int_gas/100 
        FROM dbo.prd AS P (NOLOCK)
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_compl AS W WITH (NOLOCK) ON (P.id_subsidiary = W.id_subsidiary) AND (P.id_wellborecompl = W.id) 
            left JOIN dbo.wellstring WITH (NOLOCK) ON W.id_wellstring = dbo.wellstring.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore wb WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.wellstring.id_wellbore = wb.id 
            left JOIN dbo.wellbore_permit WP WITH (NOLOCK) ON wb.id = WP.id_wellbore
            left JOIN dbo.permit  WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = WP.id_permit
            left JOIN dbo.permit_terms PT WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.permit.id = PT.id_permit 
        where (p.[date] >= pt.start_date and p.[date] <=pt.end_date)
    --      AND W.[name] = WLC.[name] 
            AND p.id = pd.id
            AND pd.id_subsidiary = w.id_subsidiary
            AND P.deletedAt Is Null 
            AND W.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.wellstring.deletedAt Is Null
            AND dbo.permit.deletedAt Is Null
            AND wb.deletedAt Is Null
            AND PT.deletedAt Is Null
    )
    as Gas_net
    FROM (dbo.prd AS PD 
    INNER JOIN dbo.wellbore_compl AS WLC ON (PD.id_subsidiary = WLC.id_subsidiary) AND (PD.id_wellborecompl = WLC.id)) 
    WHERE 
     PD.deletedAt Is Null 
    AND WLC.deletedAt Is Null
```

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you understand the consequences, at least use current syntax, not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: Change your joins to INNER JOIN - you are filtering on pt.start_date which eliminates the null values from the outer join.  Also - set an alias for *every* table referenced and use that alias for all column references.   Once you have that done - you can then move the query to a CROSS/OUTER APPLY to calculate all values you want in a 'single' query.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the quick reply. It returns very fast now except with 'Cross apply' I get zero records. With 'Outer apply' I get all of the records but Nulls for  the last 4 columns tt....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should get you close

```
Select WELLCOMPL       = WLC.name
     , SUB             = WLC.id_subsidiary
     , PD.Date
     , PD.days
     , PD.oil
     , PD.water
     , PD.gas
     , PD.interest
     , PD.operator
     , PD.comments
     , permit_interest = tt.net_working_int_oil
     , permit_operator = tt.operator
     , Oil_net         = PD.oil * tt.net_working_int_oil / 100
     , Gas_net         = PD.gas * tt.net_working_int_gas / 100
  From dbo.prd                                  PD With (NoLock)
 Inner Join dbo.wellbore_compl                 WLC With (NoLock) On PD.id_subsidiary = WLC.id_subsidiary
                                                                And pd.id_wellborecompl = WLC.id

 Cross Apply (Select PT.operator
                   , PT.net_working_int_oil
                   , PT.net_working_int_gas
                From dbo.wellstring             ws With (NoLock)
               Inner Join dbo.wellbore          wb With (NoLock) On wb.id = ws.id_wellbore
               Inner Join dbo.wellbore_permit   WP With (NoLock) On WP.id_wellbore = wb.id
               Inner Join dbo.permit             p With (NoLock) On p.id = WP.id_permit
               Inner Join dbo.permit_terms      PT With (NoLock) On PT.id_permit = p.id
         Where ws.id = WLC.id_wellstring        -- this ties us back to the outer query
           And PD.[date] >= pt.Start_Date       -- this ties back to date on outer PD table
           And pd.[date] <= pt.end_date         -- this ties back to date on outer PD table
           And ws.deletedAt Is Null
           And wb.deletedAt Is Null
           And p.deletedAt Is Null
           And PT.deletedAt Is Null
             )                                  tt

 Where PD.deletedAt Is Null
   And WLC.deletedAt Is Null;
```

As already stated - remove NOLOCK hints unless you are sure that you understand the risks associated with using it.

Now you can add any additional columns needed from the permit (PT) table and define your calculations based off those values.  This assumes you will always have related values and are only interested in showing those that actually have values.

If you need to show all, even if there is no wellstring, wellbore, permit, etc... then change the cross apply to an outer apply and you will get NULL values for all of your calculations.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. When I run your code as is, there are no records returned. When I run with 'Outer apply' I get all records but without the calculations as you stated above. My problem is that I always want all the records returned and the permit calculations when the criteria is met.

Comment: `This should get you close` is almost always going to indicate that this answer isn't actually going to answer OP's question. This answer is not a logical equivalent to OP. As pointed out by OP, this solution will limit the rows returned based on their occurrence within the subquery, which the OP's originally posted solution does not do.

Comment: @trenton-ftw - so your only contribution is to say my answer isn't correct?  Do you have any other options that you think are better?

Comment: @corpx - I think I found the problem.   The problem is in the join for dbo.wellbore  - the on statement should be: On wb.id = ws.id_wellbore.  Try making that change - I have edited the answer to reflect that change.

Comment: @Jeff - Absolutely perfect! The "OUTER" does what I need and does it fast! From 1 min+ to under 10 seconds. If I was allowed to add to your reputation, I would definitely big you up, big time! Thanks again for your time and patience. Regards.

Comment: @corpx - you are welcome.  Glad this worked for you and thank you for the feedback.  You can mark my answer - that will take care of points I think.